# How to delete mails using selenium weblements

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to delete mails in yahoo mails using selenium. I have used `id`, `xpath`, `name` etc. but I didn't succeed. Mouse operation worked well but the coordinates may differ from system to system. So is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What element locator you are using, It is good if you share your code.

Comment: share the code which have tried till now

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score -1):

Can you please share the Browser and code if you have any so that it would be easy to help you.

Actually if you are looking for opening yahoomail in firefox browser. it will be as follows:
1. open the Yahoomail in forefoxbrowser
2. inspect the element for username and send the keys to the username text box
3. inspect the element for password and send the keys to the password text box
4. click on the login/submit button

once you logged in to the welcome page
5. Try to use the xpath and traverse to the input [ie.type=checkbox]...
You have to be careful enough to use the correct xpath to get the check box.